# I'm stuck: How do I fix slow execution time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm on my way to become proficient with Python core tools.

Following code designed to list all possible permutations of 8 bit byte; as is, I have been waiting for like almost 10 minutes and the code still keep executing:

```
def duplicateList(obj):
    res = []

    for i in range(len(obj)):
        for j in range(len(obj)):
            if obj[i] == obj[j]:
                if obj[i] not in res:
                    res.append(obj[i])
    return res

def permutation(obj):
    if not obj:
        yield obj
    else:
        for i in range(len(obj)):
            others = obj[:i] + obj[i+1:]
            for j in permutation(others):
                yield obj[i:i+1] + j

def permMain(n):
    start = [0] * n
    d = [start[:]]

    for i in range(len(start)):
        if start[i] == 0:
            start[i] = 1
            d.extend(list(permutation(start)))
    return duplicateList(d)

perm = permMain(8)

print('%-13s | %5s' % ('Result lists', 'Len of lists'))

for l in range(len(perm)):
    if l == 0:
        print('%-13s | %-5s' % (perm[l], len(perm)))
    else:
        print('%-13s |' % (perm[l]))
```

I would like to reduce the waiting time for execution. Is there any way to do so?

Thank you

**Edit**:
I have found an alternative to solution provided in the answer section, though, much more work and slower than `product`. Nonetheless this the alternative:

```
from itertools import product

def duplicateList(obj):
    d = []

    for i in obj:
        if i not in d:
            d.append(i)
            yield i

def permutation(obj):
    if not obj:
        yield obj
    else:
        for i in range(len(obj)):
            others = obj[:i] + obj[i+1:]
            for j in permutation(others):
                yield obj[i:i+1] + j

def permMain(n):
    obj = [0] * n

    for i in range(len(obj)+1):
        if not any(obj):
            yield obj[:]
            obj[i] = 1
        else:
            for j in duplicateList(permutation(obj)):
                yield j
            try:
                obj[i] = 1
            except IndexError:
                break

x = sorted(permMain(8))
y = sorted([list(z) for z in product((0, 1), repeat=8)])

def printer():
    flag = 1

    print('|{!s:^24} | {!s:^23}|'.format('permMain', 'product'))

    for i, j in zip(x, y):
        if i == j: 
            continue
        else:
            flag = 0

    if flag:
        print('|{!s:^50}|'.format('permMain equals product'))

printer()
```

Here's the result:

```
|        permMain         |         product        |
|             permMain equals product              |
[Finished in 2.3s]
```

Comment: Can you change it to 2 and run with `cProfile` to see what takes how much time?

Comment: Your problem is not code structures but your algorithm. A clean code structure can only be done with a clean algorithm, as the time complexity of your code is closing to O(n^4), I suggest you to learn some cleaner algorithm for permutation first

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi I don't know yet how to cProfile. But it takes 1.2.s seconds after changed it to 2.

Comment: `import cProfile cProfile.run("permMain(8)")`

Comment: Until now, I have been reading Learning Python by Mark Lutz (Ch. 37 at the moment). For better deal with algorithm, especially for Python, do you have some recommendation  books as follow-up? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one recommendation for you: don't recode/redevelop what already exists. The power of python comes from the libraries which are often time very well written, documented, and optimized.

For instance, to generate all possible setup of `0` and `1` of size 8:

```
from itertools import product
list(product((0, 1), repeat=8))
```

And as `itertools` is far more optimized than your attempt:

```
%timeit list(product((0, 1), repeat=8))
11.3 µs ± 265 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you @Mathieu for the answer. I will try to digest as all these are very new to me.

Comment: A little design goes a long way. I'm amazed by the simplicity. Thank you for showing me this.